# IOS 5.1 using TableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, ipad

I'm trying to use the MasterDetail view with Xcode. In the given UITableView i changed the content type to static content and added three columns. But if i run this project now in the iPad emulator this table cells / rows aren't shown :/ ... what else I have to do in order to make this cells visible? Is there somewhere an simple tutorial how to setup an UITableView with static content?

Thanks and regards,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Check this. It would really help you :)

CS193p Lecture 10 pdf File: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/lectures/Lecture%2010.pdf

Video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OaiGn-W4bwU

Vocabulous (Check the vid, that's the code of the demo): http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/sample_code/Vocabulous.zip